# "Centralising" a "decentral" design

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb

I have a web app using a database per client (around 120 and growing, 20k users in total). Each database has its own `user` table with `user_id`, `username`, `password`, etc. Meaning: if a user is member of multiple sites, the user has multiple accounts, passwords, etc.

I want to "centralise" the `user` tables, so users can log in once for all sites they are member of.

The username is the email address; which is used on a lot of places in the app.

Ideally I'd use a few "centralised" tables (`user` with columns `username`, `password`, etc; `login_has_site` linking `user` with `site`), while leaving the "decentralised" `user` tables untouched (containing `username` but also site specific preferences).

But, how do you maintain integrity between "central" and "decentral" tables when e.g. email address changes? Looking for strategy/ how to approach. Any thoughts?

### Additional information

**Basic schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `login` (
  `login_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  `salt` text NOT NULL  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `login_has_site` (
  `login_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_start` date NOT NULL,
  `date_end` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- In each client database:
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `login_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  -- other fields  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What would be the advantage of recording the `user_id` in the "client" database in the "central" database vs storing `login_id` in the "client" database?

Also: the `username` column is referenced in a lot of places in the codebase. Would it be wise to make it a key in the central database and use e.g. `on update cascade` to maintain integrity, while not having to rewrite all code?

Comment: First, decide on how to deal with the odd cases -- same user name but different email address; or same email address but different user name; etc.  You may discover a dozen different reasons, some excusable, some not, for the descrepancies.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a single common database. In this common database create your user table.

Instead of a login_has_site field, have a table of access that can be joined:

- primary user id (of common table)
- client name (other database)
- user id in client db

After you have have that you can start to deprecate the fields in the user table across all but the common database's user table.

Comment: Thanks Dan, helpful. Have added some additional questions.